# Loop through each element in Swagger yaml in Go

Tags: go, yaml, swagger

I am trying to loop through all the paths and methods in a Swagger document using Golang and get few fields from that, for eg: to get the value of operationId for each path and method.
Below is the sample Swagger document -

```
swagger: "2.0"
host: "petstore.swagger.io"
basePath: "/v2"
schemes:
- "https"
- "http"
paths:
  /pet:
    post:
      tags:
      - "pet"
      summary: "Add a new pet to the store"
      operationId: "addPet"
    put:
      tags:
      - "pet"
      summary: "Update an existing pet"
      operationId: "updatePet"
  /pet/findByStatus:
    get:
      tags:
      - "pet"
      summary: "Finds Pets by status"
      operationId: "findPetsByStatus"
```

This Swagger document is not static and it will change. So I have not defined a struct for this as paths and methods will not remain same.
Below is the sample code -

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

func main() {

m := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
}
fmt.Printf("--- m:\n%v\n\n", m)

for k, v := range m {
    fmt.Println(k, ":", v)
    }
}
```

I am able to print the map like below -

```
paths : map[/pet:map[post:map[operationId:addPet summary:Add a new pet to the store tags:[pet]] put:map[operationId:updatePet summary:Update an existing pet tags:[pet]]] /pet/findByStatus:map[get:map[operationId:findPetsByStatus summary:Finds Pets by status tags:[pet]]]]
```

How can I print each path and method like below -

```
/pet post addPet
/pet put updatePet
/pet/findByStatus get findPetsByStatus
```

Comment: Consider using an OpenAPI parser such as [this one](https://github.com/getkin/kin-openapi) instead of a generic YAML parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of options, use a https://github.com/getkin/kin-openapi to parse your YAML. The example below will require you to convert your YAML to JSON.

```
    t := &openapi2.T{}

    if err := t.UnmarshalJSON([]byte(jsdata)); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for path, item := range t.Paths {
        for method, op := range item.Operations() {
            fmt.Printf("%s %s %s\n", path, method, op.OperationID)
        }
    }
```

Or you can continue to use type assertion and for loops.

```
func main() {

    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }

    for k, v := range m {
        if k != "paths" {
            continue
        }

        m2, ok := v.(map[interface{}]interface{})
        if !ok {
            continue
        }

        if ok {
            for path, x := range m2 {
                m3, ok := x.(map[interface{}]interface{})
                if !ok {
                    continue
                }
                for method, x := range m3 {
                    m4, ok := x.(map[interface{}]interface{})
                    if !ok {
                        continue
                    }
                    operationId, ok := m4["operationId"]
                    if !ok {
                        continue
                    }
                    fmt.Println(path, method, operationId)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jmaloney, I am able to parse Swagger documents using "kin-openapi". I used below package to convert the yaml to Json -

`github.com/ghodss/yaml`
```
swagger, err := yaml.YAMLToJSON([]byte(definition))
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err)
  return
 }
```
I am able to read all the fields from swagger except the custom ones like"x-ignoreoperation" in below example -

```
"/pet":
  get:
    x-ignoreoperation: true
    operationId: findPetsByStatus
```
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/openapi-extensions/
How these custom fields also can be read using this?